# Valar Morghulis, Arya Stark and Daario Naharis - Connection?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Arya Stark was given a coin and taught the phrase *"valar morghulis"*. In the TV-series season 2, after she kills a man, she takes back the coin she was given and says those words.

Daario Naharis, who was introduced in season 3, says the same words when he receives the coin that means he is given the task to kill Dany.

Having read the books,

> I know Arya uses the coin to travel to the House of Black and White where she learns to change.

Is there a connection between Daario and this place, or is there no significance to these two characters using the same phrase with the coins?

Comment: I agree that Jaqen and Daario may be the same person. In a Clash of kings, Jaqen takes a new face that has a hooked nose; curly hair and a golden tooth. All of these are traits shared with Daario

Answer (score 37):

*Valar Morghulis* is a phrase in High Valyrian that is commonly used in the [Free Cities](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Free_Cities), which means "All men must die". Both Jaqen H'ghar (who taught that phrase to Arya) and Daario are from the Free Cities (Lorath and Tyrosh respectively),  So it's not surprising to see it used by both men.

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen any of the information speculating (based on book text) that Jaqen, the Alchemist, and Darrio are the same person? What do you think?

Comment: @Bern - Too early to tell. Jaqen has been theorized to be almost everyone in Westeros by now.

Comment: I've not seen anything suggesting that Darrio and Jaqen are the same man, but I'm a firm believer that Jaqen and Syrio are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that Jaqen and Syrio are the same. Darrio's travels make it seem impossible that he and Jaqen are the same. I didn't realize the phrase was common in all the free cities - I thought it was exclusive to Bravos - thanks for the insights!

Comment: @Bern - Glad to be of help. Don't forget to accept this answer if you found it useful. And welcome to SF&F!

Comment: @CL4PTR4P:Jaqen and Syrio are not the same. George RR Martin is not that lame in his storytelling.

Comment: M Night Shalamar Twist: Jaqen is Arya.

Comment: @Nick - It's a twist!

Comment: No evidence whatsoever to support Jaqen being Syrio, btw. 1- like Jakob says, GRRM is not that lame. 2- Syrio dies at the hands of guards. That we do not see this happen "on screen" doesn't mean it didn't happen.

Comment: @Nick The Twist: Jaquen H'ghar is actually Ned Stark...who is also Tyler Durden from Fight Club

Answer (score 5):

In the show, [Mero](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mero) gave the coin to Daario. And as we all know, Jaqen gives another Braavosi coin to Arya before they part ways. The connection is that both Mero and Jaqen are affiliated with Bravos.

This quote from a [review of the episode](http://towerofthehand.com/blog/2013/05/22-review-second-sons/index.html) sums it up nicely:

> Mero's method of drawing a random coin to determine who gets the job of assassin was a brilliant addition to the world of Game of Thrones; it's not in the books, but it makes so much sense for the killer to be the one who draws the Braavosi coin (not only because it's Mero's land of origin, but because of the association with the Faceless Men) that it makes you wonder why Martin didn't think of that himself.

Comment: It's a POV series, so not every detail can be covered in the books without resorting to too much clunky exposition. I expect Martin still had a hand in that scene. Have you read the books? Not wanting to spoil anything, but there's a prominent chapter in A Dance with Dragons which links a Braavosi coin and an assassination attempt....

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a connection between Jaqen H'ghar and Daario Naharis (in fact I believe them to be the same person).  In addition to using the phrase "valar morghulis" (which may be a common phrase in Bravos),  both characters separately use another phrase.  In the scenes between Jaqen and Ayrya, Jaqen  refers to her as 'lovely girl' on numerous occasions.  Daario also uses the phrase 'lovely girl', when he is sent to kill the Mother of Dragons and releases her handmaiden/freed-slave. It's a very subtle use of a very specific phrase, which when combined with the 'valar morghulis', the faceless man, and other elements, leads me to the conclusion Jagen and Daario are one and the same.

Answer (score 2):

So just because we see 1 of the Faceless Men in the series everybody has to assume that there is only 1?? Men is a plural as far as i know!  And how would the Faceless men be any good at their job if there was a finite number of them?? the entire seting does not start and stop with Westeros. there are other continents/landmasses that arent touched by the series yet.

Comment: Well, there ARE a finite number of them. There cannot be infinitly many Faceless men...however, I agree that the assumption that every faceless man is the same is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I read the books, but I was reading Jaqen's AWOIAF page, and it decribes him as changing into a man with "a hook nose, a gold tooth, and curly hair", which almost exactly matches Daario's description.

Comment: Can you link to the correct page and offer some more information about how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Valar Morghulis means *"All Men Must Die.*" It is High Valyrian. Arya Stark is told these words and given an Iron coin by Jaqen H'ghar. We've seen her enter the House of Black and White with these words. There is so far no connection in the show between Jaqen and Daario except for the fact that they were both given coins, which may mean that there is a connection in who the coins come from and why.**POSSIBLE SPOILER**We know also that Jaqen may or may not be the Many Faced God or just one of an order of assassins.** Daario was the best fighter in the pits, he could very well be an assassin, but we have so far seen no evidence that he was hired to carry out an assassination in particular at all.

Valar Dohaeris means *"All Men Must Serve"* It is customary to respond this way to Valar Morghulis.

Daario Naharis is a Tyroshi sellsword who in S3 is a lieutenant of the Second Sons. He is introduced played by a different actor, who comes to a meeting with the Second Sons and Daenerys Targaryan. He then returns played by Michiel Huisman, from S4 on. His role gets much larger as he takes over the Second Sons by killing the two leaders above him. He falls in love with Daenerys at first sight and eventually becomes her second/third in command, counseling her on many things, including re-opening the fighting pits. She falls in love with Daario, although she marries Hizdar for peace, which makes Daario angry. At the end of Season 5, Daenerys has flown off on Drogon, ending up surrounded by Dothraki. Daario and Jorah Mormont go off together to save her, while Tyrion runs the city of Meereen with Grey Worm and Missandei watching over the Unsullied.  There are many theories of the true identities of both men. The question has not yet been answered. **POSSIBLE SPOILER** Daario could be the leader of the Sons of the Harpy, in some fan's opinions.**

Answer (score -1):

Remember when Arya and Jaqen were about to cross paths, Jaqen changed his face.
Therefore, there might be a possibility that Jaqen is Daario.

Answer (score -3):

I think it might be a special brotherhood of Khaleesi. Valar Morghulis being the words of their brotherhood or possibly these people are actually fighting for Khaleesi. Considering she is the only female conqueror in the series.